# Given a category $\mathcal{C}$, is $\mathcal{C} = (\mathcal{C}^{OP})^{OP}$ true?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

The way I understand the definition of $\mathcal{C}^{OP}$, it is the case that $\mathcal{C}(X, Y) = \mathcal{C}^{OP}(Y,X)$ for every pair of objects $X, Y$.

Consider the category $(\mathcal{C}^{OP})^{OP}$, it has the same objects as $\mathcal{C}$, and for every pair of objects $X, Y$, $\mathcal{C}(X, Y)$ and $(\mathcal{C}^{OP})^{OP}(X, Y)$ coincide, having the same morphism and composition rules. I take $\mathcal{C}$ and $(\mathcal{C}^{OP})^{OP}$ to be the same.

But does $\mathcal{C} = (\mathcal{C}^{OP})^{OP}$ implies that every functor is covariant and contravariant at the same time? Does it imply that every covariant functor can also be viewed as a contravariant functor?

Comment: A contravariant functor $\mathcal C\to\mathcal D$ is just a covariant functor $\mathcal C^{op}\to\mathcal D$.

Comment: To confirm the question in the title, it is true that $(\mathcal C^{\mathrm{op}})^{\mathrm{op}} = \mathcal C$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, $(\mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op})^\mathrm{op} = \mathcal{C}$.  This is a check of the definition.

Thus a covariant functor $F: \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ may be regarded as a contravariant one $F: \mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op} \to \mathcal{D}$ and vice versa.  So, I suppose, yes, every functor *may* be viewed as contra- or covariant, but that requires a change of the domain, so this is not the "same" functor.